# Issue when getting BrightnessLevel in UWP apps

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, screen-brightness

There is something strange for me with BrightnessOverride. I can modify the brightness level and then get its new value, but, if I don't change it, a value equal to zero is returned.

VB Code:

```
Private bo As BrightnessOverride
bo = BrightnessOverride.GetForCurrentView()
Debug.WriteLine(bo.BrightnessLevel) ' I get 0
bo.StartOverride()
Debug.WriteLine(bo.BrightnessLevel) ' I get 0
bo.SetBrightnessLevel(0.25, DisplayBrightnessOverrideOptions.None)
Debug.WriteLine(bo.BrightnessLevel) ' I get 0.25
```

Moreover, it's not possible to read (only read) the system brightness level even if I add the the SystemManagement capability. I get an error like some other stackoverflow members.

I made the same test with C# and there is of course the same problem.

As some stackoverflow members got successfully the right brightness value some months ago ([UWP: BrightnessOverride StartOverride logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644723/uwp-brightnessoverride-startoverride-logic)), it definitively seems that there is an issue with the last version of Windows and/or VS (2017).

Comment: Notorious problem, exactly what causes it is hard to reverse-engineer because programmers with this problem never describe their hardware.  But the MSDN article makes no bones about it, noting "on devices that support controllable brightness".  You can tell it doesn't.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment but I confirm that there is absolutely no problem with the hardware to change the brightness on my 2-in-1 computer; whatever the method which is used. The only problem is when using UWP code. Even with powershell script, that works.

Answer (score 1):

We have filed an issue on the Github, you can check it here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/516

If you want to get the current brightness from the system, you'd need a [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) with a desktop app to fetch the current Brightness (as opposed to the current override) using win32 approach here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-getmonitorbrightness.

Comment: Thanks, but I already created a feedback in Github with learn.microsoft.com :

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.brightnessoverride.brightnesslevel#Windows_Graphics_Display_BrightnessOverride_BrightnessLeve][1]l

and 

[https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22e5cff65f-4c9b-93ae-8ff6-815580e7e505%22&in=body][1]